# Does apps script DriveApp and it's associated classes provide a way to add a new version to a file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Without using Advanced Drive Services, is it possible to add a new version to a Drive file in Apps Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
function openfilechangecontents(x) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById("id");
  file.setContent(x);
}
```

Comment: !! I've been using this all along, thinking it just replaced the contents of the current version, but I see that instead it does just what I wanted!